# rails3 displaying related values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

a class has_many materials which has_many colors.  Attempting to display the results in a cascading manner, as follows

```
  <% @materials.each do |material| %>
      <%= material.name %> <br />
      <% params[:material_id] =  material.id %>
      <%= material.color.name %><br />
      <% @colors = Color.where(['id = ?', params[:material_id]]).all %>
      <% @colors.each do |color| %>
         <%= color.name %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

is generating strange lists. one list for a first material shows a color of another material, which the second material shows a proper color, but only 1 of the valid ones, notwithstanding the controller states for the show action

```
@model = Model.find(params[:id])
@materials = Material.where(['collection_id = ?', @model.collection_id]).all
@color = Color.new
```

That last bit is because we allow the user to create a color for the given material at the end of the list.

What is the logic that is confusing rails?

Answer (score 1):

you are violating a lot of best practices

- don't assign stuff to `params` like `params[:material_id] =  material.id` especially in views
- don't call finders in views like `Color.where(['id = ?', params[:material_id]]).all`
- avoid assigning instance-variables like `@color` in the view
- don't call a model `Model` that will probably result in confusing behavior and runtime errors

you are also not relying on rails object relational mapping capabilities.

if you have setup a model correctly with `has_many` and `belongs_to` you can just call methods on a record fetched from the database like `@model.materials`.

when all is properly coded, your show action looks like this:

```
def show
  @model = Model.find(params[:id])
end
```

and the view like this

```
<% @model.materials.each do |material| %>
  <%= material.name %><br>
  <% material.colors.each do |color| %>
     <%= color.name %><br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Model was not actually the real class name.  @color was being instantiated in the controller.  Reply useful stating 'if you have setup correctly...'; the relationships were wrong. They ought to have been HABTM, which changes things significantly.